# Datatable with data coming from two different sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I'm currently using jquery datatable plugin to show a paginated view of data with Search & Sort filters. The server (server1) returns the data in JSON format.The search filter makes an AJAX call to Server1 and it returns the matching sets of data. Pagination does the same.

Now I also need to pull additional data from server2 (also returns JSON) and append it to the original datatable data (pulled from server1) while retaining search/sort filters.

I originally thought of pulling data from both these sources separately, merging the data and then drawing a datatable that shows the aggregated view. But the amount of data is so huge that a call to pull all data takes a good few minutes. I can change the Servers (Server1 & Sever2) to return focused data (by accepting params such as fromData, toDate, number of records etc.).

Limitation: Both servers can't talk to each other unfortunately. Had they been able to communicate, I could've done the aggregation in one backend and make it easy for datatables.

So to sum up:

- Data comes from multiple sources - Server1 & Server2
- Cannot pull all data at once
- Retain Search/Sort filters

Is it possible to achieve this with datatables? If not is there an alternative javascript solution that does this (in some form that can be programmatically extended).

Comment: have you considered having one server make call to other server and combine data into one ajax call?

Comment: I don't know how you would sort & filter successfully with aggregating the data somehow. Can the servers communicate with each other?  perhaps you could use a stored procedure as the datasource. The stored proc would aggregate the data and return it to the datatable.

Comment: @charlietfl  Sorry I left that detail out. Both servers can't talk to each other by design. That would've solved this problem. I will update the post with this detail.

Comment: @markpsmith Updated the question with the limitation. Both servers cannot communicate with each other. Server1 is a typical Java web service while Server2 is a javascript based frame2frame communication framework (weird!).

Comment: @uhsarp that doesn't make sense, servers can make http requests just like browser can or use curl requests

Comment: @charlietfl I know. It made no sense to me either. So the server2 identifies a SSO (Single Sign on) token/cookie in the browser and returns the logged in user's data. By design, this communication with Server2 can only happen in the browser (It is weird as heck).

Comment: well if you can't proxy the auth headers, I don't know if datatables supports multiple sources internally but you could manage the requests using `$.when` to aggregate when both requests are done, then pass the data to the plugin

Comment: @charlietfl I'm thinking about doing the same. Do you know if I can call a javascript function (lets say merge()) when a user clicks on a different page number or does a search/sort in datatables? That way I can put the merge/aggregation code in merge(), which will be invoked when user requests data that isn't already loaded.

Comment: can likely tie into events within plugin but the disconnect bewteen plugin and internal data handling could be complicated. You might have to rewrite the ajax in plugin itself which might be simplest path